# backup script to copy files by its extension

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, quoting, newlines

I have created script to copy `.png` files from one directory to another. Script is as follows:

```
i="`cat /usr/local/app1/default.conf | grep -i values | sed -e 's/\values=//g' -e 's/,/ /g'`"
for data in $i
do
cp -rvp /usr/local/dir1/$data.png /home/user1/dir1
done
```

When I run the above script, this copies files from `dir1` to `/home/user/dir1` but at the end giving me error such as:

`cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/local/dir1/wasw\r.png’: No such file or directory`

contents in `default.conf`:

```
 values= wads sead seda okaw wasw
```

The command `cp` searches for these values 'wads', 'sead' etc but at the end I am getting the above error..

Comment: Is it possible the file was edited on Windows (or an old mac)? It looks like there are `\r` which probably points that there are wrong line-endings in the file.

Comment: Please try this : `cp - rvf /path_from_where_youwanttocopyfiles/*.png /home/user1/dir1/` Or use find command and grep png files and copy them to to desired directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the same code as you currently have, I suggest using `sed` a little more to its capacity :

```
i="`sed -n 's/'$'\r''//;s/,/ /g;s/values=//gp' /usr/local/app1/default.conf`"
for data in $i; do
    cp -rvp /usr/local/dir1/$data.png /home/user1/dir1
done
```

**How it works :**

- The `-n` flag to `sed` tells it to not print the lines automatically
- The `s/$'\r'//` statement removes the `\r` characters that is probably causing your problems
- The added `p` at the end of the `s/values=//gp` statement prints the buffer only if a replacement was made (only if `values=` was present on the line)

Comment: @Shri I'm glad it did. To help others find the answer when confronted to a similar problem, it would be nice to accept the answer by selecting the little check mark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't get your use case, but all I understood is you want to find `.png` files from a directory and want to copy those files to another directory.If my understanding about your use case is correct then the below command helps,

`find /home/your/source/path/ -name \*.png -exec cp {} /home/your/destination/path/ \;`

Answer (score 0):

You probably edited that default.conf file on windows machine and copied it over. There seems to be an extra character at the end of that line before the newline. Try `od -c default.conf`. It probably gives you something like:

```
0000000   v   a   l   u   e   s   =       w   a   d   s       s   e   a
0000020   d       s   e   d   a       o   k   a   w       w   a   s   w
0000040 022  \n
0000042
```

Edit the file to remove the `022` character (which is `\r`) and try again.